# MS Access. SQL. get current time

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access and I'm trying to build SQL query. I have this table:
`VISIT
VISIT_ID DATE_OF_VISIT COST`.
I need to get current date in query, then I need to get year from this date, then I need to get sums of money for each month of that year as a result.
Does anyone know how to get current date?
Do I need to use some sort of cycles?

Comment: did you try to use `Date()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Month(date_of_visit), Sum(cost)
FROM VISIT
WHERE Year(date_of_visit) = Year(Date())
GROUP BY Month(date_of_visit);
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, for a query like this, I use the design tool.  If I want the SQL, I use the design tool and then select the SQL view. Within the design tool, consider using the date() function or the now() function, or take a look at Access help.  There are a number of options available and one should give you exactly what you are needing. That way, MS Access does all the coding work.